# firebase push notification , intent not working

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent

I have an android project **MyProj.Android** and another android class library project **MyCls** which handles the push notification.

click on push notification I need to open the activity **PromotionActivity**.

**click_action** = "Myproj.Droid.PromotionActivity" &
**Android package name** = "com.MyPckage"

```
namespace Myproj.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "PromotionActivity")]
    public class PromotionActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
    ----------
```

How do I create intent for this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.SetClassName("com.MyPckage", "Myproj.Droid.PromotionActivity");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, requestID, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot); 
    builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        
    var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
     NotificationManager.Notify(notification_id, builder.Build());
```

Please help me on this issue. Thanks